# Laravel how to display all HTTP error codes in JSON?

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, http-error, httpexception

As I create a REST API, I want all 404 and 403 errors displayed as JSON. When I try to return a message, the message is empty, but the error codes are usually displayed. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm using PHP 8 and Laravel 9.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'current_password',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    public function register()
    {
        $this->renderable(function (Throwable $e, $request) {
            $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');

            if ($e instanceof HttpExceptionInterface && $request->wantsJson()) {
                $code = $e->getStatusCode() ?: 400;
                $message = $e->getMessage() ?: 'Invalid Request.';

                return response(['success' => false, 'message' => $message], $code);
            }
        });

        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
            //
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try `abort()` https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/errors#http-exceptions

Comment: But this will not return an error message to me, just a page with an error. And I want, for example, for the code 404 it returns in the message, for example, Not Found, for 403 Forbridden, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to return response in json format like

```
return response()->json([
    'code' => 404
]);
```

and if you gonna try your api in postman do not forget to add

```
Accept: application/json
```

in headers.

Comment: I can see that you have not read carefully because I have exactly done the return, but it does not return the message about the code

Comment: You have to add your controller logic to your answer. So we can see what you are doing wrong. Showing Handler class doesn't make sense in your situation.

Comment: Why is she responsible for popping errors 404, 403, 400, etc.?